# How to add state tax in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to assign state tax to transactions but I'm really new to Javascript.

I'm trying to have a different tax amount by state. Also I don't want it to auto generate the subtotal at $100.

Where am I going wrong? I'm totally lost.

I've tried to add the different tax amount as new if variable but when I do it gets rid of the tax for all trans.

```js
function taxRate() {
    var tax_rate = .07;
    var order_taxes = 0;
    var tax_percent = 0;
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("order_subtotal").innerHTML;
    subtotal = parseInt(subtotal);
    var total = 0;
    var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    if (state === 'NY') {
      order_taxes += +(tax_rate * subtotal).toFixed(2);
      tax_percent = +(tax_rate * 100).toFixed(2);
    }
    if (state === 'NJ') {
      order_taxes += +(tax_rate * subtotal).toFixed(2);
      tax_percent = +(tax_rate * 100).toFixed(2);
    }
    if (state === 'VA') {
      order_taxes += +(tax_rate * subtotal).toFixed(2);
      tax_percent = +(tax_rate * 100).toFixed(2);
    }
    if (state === 'AL') {
      order_taxes += +(tax_rate * subtotal).toFixed(2);
      tax_percent = +(tax_rate * 100).toFixed(2);
    }

    var el = document.getElementById('order_tax');
    el.textContent = order_taxes;

    var total = subtotal + order_taxes;
    var el1 = document.getElementById('order_total');
    el1.textContent = total;
    document.getElementById('tax_percent').value = tax_percent;
}
```

```html
<div id="public">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="city">CITY</label>
        <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="city input-small form-control" placeholder="CITY"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="state">STATE</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="state" onChange="taxRate()">
          <option value="">N/A</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
          <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="CA">California</option>
          <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
          <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
          <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
          <option value="FL">Florida</option>
          <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
          <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
          <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
          <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
          <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
          <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
          <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
          <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
          <option value="ME">Maine</option>
          <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
          <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
          <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
          <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
          <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
          <option value="MT">Montana</option>
          <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
          <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
          <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
          <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="NY">New York</option>
          <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
          <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
          <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
          <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
          <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
          <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="TX">Texas</option>
          <option value="UT">Utah</option>
          <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
          <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
          <option value="WA">Washington</option>
          <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
          <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" id="tax_percent" name="tax_percent">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zipCode">ZIP CODE</label>
        <input id="zip" type="text" size="6" autocomplete="off" class="zipcode form-control" placeholder="ZIP CODE"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- Closes Public -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
            <label>ORDER INFORMATION</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
            <label>SUBTOTAL: <b>$<span id="order_subtotal">100</span></b></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
            <label>TAXES: <b><span id="order_tax" type="text" value=""></span></b></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
            <label>ORDER TOTAL: <b><span id="order_total" type="text" value=""></span></b></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well Java !== JavaScript

Comment: Hey Steven, it would be nice if you add a minimal working example. There are quite a few points where the error could occur. Your code looks okay, but all the document.getElement... parts may contain an error. You can do this with the Snippet-Button in the Editor.

Comment: I've put your code into a snippet, and everything is working fine.

Comment: Yes that is actually perfect. The only thing now is that with that code it only generates that rate for 100$ for example: in the code you fixed it has the tax rate at for subtotal of 100$. So if i make the sale 200$ its doubling that tax rate. I just want the standard percent to apply no matter what the subtotal is. Sorry if im being alittle confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make "order_subtotal" editable.
I've changed the span to an input and changed line 5 of the script from innterHTML to value.
As far as I see everything is calculated correctly.

Another point is, that the DropDown Menu triggers the taxRate() function therefore if you first set the city and then type a subtotal you need to change the city again to trigger the calculation.

I set the trigger on the subtotal input additionally.

And at least I set the tax_rate individually per state (some fake rates) and put the calculation at the end.

```js
function taxRate() {
var tax_rate = .07;
var order_taxes = 3.25;
var tax_percent = 0;
var subtotal = document.getElementById("order_subtotal").value;
subtotal = parseInt(subtotal);
var total = 0;
var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
if (state === 'AL') {
  tax_rate = .04;
}
if (state === 'AK') {
  tax_rate = .00;
} 
if (state === 'AZ') {
  tax_rate = .056;
}
if (state === 'AR') {
  tax_rate = .065;
}
if (state === 'CA') {
  tax_rate = .07;
}
if (state === 'CO') {
  tax_rate = .029;
} 
if (state === 'CT') {
  tax_rate = .063;
}
if (state === 'DE') {
  tax_rate = .00;
}
if (state === 'FL') {
  tax_rate = .06;
}
if (state === 'GA') {
  tax_rate = .04;
}
if (state === 'HI') {
  tax_rate = .00;
} 
if (state === 'ID') {
  tax_rate = .056;
}
if (state === 'IL') {
  tax_rate = .065;
}
if (state === 'IN') {
  tax_rate = .07;
}
if (state === 'IA') {
  tax_rate = .06;
} 
if (state === 'KS') {
  tax_rate = .065;
}
if (state === 'KY') {
  tax_rate = .06;
}
if (state === 'LA') {
  tax_rate = .05;
}
if (state === 'ME') {
  tax_rate = .055;
} 
if (state === 'MD') {
  tax_rate = .06;
}
if (state === 'MA') {
  tax_rate = .0625;
}
if (state === 'MI') {
  tax_rate = .06;
}
if (state === 'MN') {
  tax_rate = .068;
} 
if (state === 'MS') {
  tax_rate = .07;
}
if (state === 'MO') {
  tax_rate = .042;
}
if (state === 'MT') {
  tax_rate = .00;
}
if (state === 'NE') {
  tax_rate = .04;
}
if (state === 'NV') {
  tax_rate = .068;
} 
if (state === 'NH') {
  tax_rate = .00;
}
if (state === 'NM') {
  tax_rate = .051;
}
if (state === 'NJ') {
  tax_rate = .07;
}
if (state === 'NY') {
  tax_rate = .04;
} 
if (state === 'NC') {
  tax_rate = .047;
}
if (state === 'ND') {
  tax_rate = .05;
}
if (state === 'OH') {
  tax_rate = .057;
}
if (state === 'OK') {
  tax_rate = .045;
}
if (state === 'OR') {
  tax_rate = .0;
}
if (state === 'PA') {
  tax_rate = .06;
}
if (state === 'RI') {
  tax_rate = .07;
}
if (state === 'SC') {
  tax_rate = .06;
}
if (state === 'SD') {
  tax_rate = .045;
}
if (state === 'TN') {
  tax_rate = .07;
}
if (state === 'TX') {
  tax_rate = .062;
}
if (state === 'UT') {
  tax_rate = .059;
}
if (state === 'VT') {
  tax_rate = .06;
}
if (state === 'VA') {
  tax_rate = .053;
}
if (state === 'WA') {
  tax_rate = .065;
}
if (state === 'WV') {
  tax_rate = .06;
}
if (state === 'WI') {
  tax_rate = .05;
}
if (state === 'WY') {
  tax_rate = .04;
}
order_taxes += +(tax_rate * subtotal).toFixed(2);
tax_percent = +(tax_rate * 100).toFixed(2);

var el = document.getElementById('order_tax');
el.textContent = order_taxes;

var total = subtotal + order_taxes;
var el1 = document.getElementById('order_total');
el1.textContent = total;
document.getElementById('tax_percent').value = tax_percent;
}
```

```html
<div id="public">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="city">CITY</label>
                                  <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" class="city input-small form-control" placeholder="CITY" />
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="state">STATE</label>
                                  <select class="form-control" id="state" onChange="taxRate()">
                                      <option value="">N/A</option>
                                      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                                      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                                      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                                      <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                                      <option value="CA">California</option>  
                                      <option value="CO">Colorado</option>  
                                      <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>  
                                      <option value="DE">Delaware</option>  
                                      <option value="FL">Florida</option>  
                                      <option value="GA">Georgia</option>  
                                      <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>  
                                      <option value="ID">Idaho</option>  
                                      <option value="IL">Illinois</option>  
                                      <option value="IN">Indiana</option>  
                                      <option value="IA">Iowa</option>  
                                      <option value="KS">Kansas</option>  
                                      <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>  
                                      <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>  
                                      <option value="ME">Maine</option> 
                                      <option value="MD">Maryland</option> 
                                      <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> 
                                      <option value="MI">Michigan</option> 
                                      <option value="MN">Minnesota</option> 
                                      <option value="MS">Mississippi</option> 
                                      <option value="MO">Missouri</option> 
                                      <option value="MT">Montana</option> 
                                      <option value="NE">Nebraska</option> 
                                      <option value="NV">Nevada</option> 
                                      <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> 
                                      <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                                      <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                                      <option value="NY">New York</option>
                                      <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                                      <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                                      <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                                      <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                                      <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                                      <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                                      <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                                      <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                                      <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                                      <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                                      <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                                      <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                                      <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                                      <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                                      <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                                      <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                                      <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                                      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>  
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="tax_percent" name="tax_percent">
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="zipCode">ZIP CODE</label>
                                  <input id="zip" type="text" size="6" autocomplete="off" class="zipcode form-control" placeholder="ZIP CODE"/>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div> <!-- Closes Public -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                                <label>ORDER INFORMATION</label>                                                        
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                                <label>SUBTOTAL: <b>$<input type="number" id="order_subtotal" placeholder="Subtotal" onChange="taxRate()" /></b></label>                                                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                                <label>TAXES: <b><span id="order_tax" type="text" value=""></span></b></label>                                                                  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                                <label>ORDER TOTAL: <b><span id="order_total" type="text" value=""></span></b></label>                                                                  
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Yes that is actually perfect. The only thing now is that with that code it only generates that rate for 100$ for example: in the code you fixed it has the tax rate at for subtotal of 100$. So if i make the sale 200$ its doubling that tax rate. I just want the standard percent to apply no matter what the subtotal is. Sorry if im being alittle confusing.

Comment: I don't get what you want? It's applying the tax_rate to the subtotal the user types in. Enter a subtotal you'll see a sum plus 0.07 percent. If you switch to a preset state (eg AL) you'll get a percentage of 0.05. You can also change the subtotal and everything will be applied. You need to add the tax_rates of the other states yourself.

Comment: for example NY tax is set to 5%. it will only charge 5% if the subtotal is $100 but when i choose 200$ it doubles the tax rate to 10% instead of the 5% thats needed. So basically for every hundred dollars its applying the tax rate. so if i tried to charge 3oo$ its would make the tax percent 15%. How do i fix?

Comment: Oh okay, I think you don't know how percentages work.... What you are describing is first of all wrong, the tax rate isn't doubled, because e.g. 5% of 100$ = 5$ and 5% of 200$ = 10$. Nothing is doubled, it's percent therefore a ratio of the percentage and the given value.  10% of 200$ is 20$ but as stated above it (tax rate) is not doubled. For your 300$ example and 10%: 100$ * 10% = 10$ and 300$*10% = 30$. What you seem to ask is only to apply the tax rate to a given maximum... But please give some example for the behaviour you want, without confusing the basics of percent values.

Comment: lol wow Im a total moron. I was looking at it visually. Now that you broke it down makes perfect sense. My apologies for such a dumb question. And thanks a bunch for your input with this code.

Comment: if i wasnted to add a convenience fee to this form how would i add that would the will i just have to add: var servicefee=.0325 into the Java code

Comment: If you want to make it constant yes. And then make the correct calculation. Nothing to thank for, Iam happy that I could help you.

Comment: I have this full out code that and everything is working perfectly now that the tax is squared away.  I want to display the full out code with html and javascript but Its says I have too many characters.

Comment: Where is it said?

Comment: Can I do a screen share with you and show you what I mean?

Comment: As I am just on my laptop and in an working environment, it's not possible this week.